# Insert, update or delete into relational tables using Sqlalchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three tables like this,

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    password = Column(String(12))

    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")
    streets = relationship("Street", backref="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(50))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

class Street(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'street'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

I am inserting data using Sqlalchemy ORM like this,

```
jack = User(name='jack', fullname='Jack Bean', password='gjffdd')
jack.addresses = [Address(email='jack@google.com'),Address(email='j25@yahoo.com')]
jack.streets = [Street(name='street1'),Street(name='street2')]
session.add(jack)
session.commit()
```

How i can insert, update or delete data into 'adress' table later using Swlalchemy ORM.

For example , insert into adress table where user_id is equal to id of 'jack' in the user table.

I couldn't find a good documentation regrding this topic, if anyone have just pass me the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jacks_new_address = Address(email='newjack@google.com', user = jack)
session.add(jacks_new_address)
```

For updating and deleting, you need to get the object from the DB via a query first, then alter or .delete() them. Loads of information on how to build query objects in the SQLAlchemy documentation....

Answer (score 0):

I would perform a query to grab all the User object, then simply assign jack.addresses as usual.

```
jack = session.query(User).filter(User.id == 12345).first()
jack.addresses = [Address(email='jack@google.com'),Address(email='j25@yahoo.com')]
```